# Reference a variable in a test script

Tags: ruby

I have created a deck class and have defined one of the functions to insert a card at the beginning of the array. However everytime I try to test it in my test script I receive `add_to_bottom': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError). Can someone please help me I know I am close to figuring it out.

Deck Class

```
def add_to_bottom
  @cards.insert(0, c)
end
```

Test Script

```
d = Deck.new
c = Card.new(7, "S")
d.add_to_bottom(c)
print d, "\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

`add_to_bottom` has `c` in the method body, which is neither a method nor a variable. If that is meant to be an argument passed, then you need to write `def add_to_bottom(c)`. If you do that, then that would also resolve your error.

Answer (score 0):

Your add_to_bottom expect no arguments while in the test code you provide an argument. Did you forget to declare it in your function declaration?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your `Deck` or `Card` classes are implemented, so it is hard to say. One very obvious problem is what @sawa and @VuMinhTan have already pointed out. So, as they said, you definitely should be taking in parameter `c` in the method you defined (`add_to_bottom`).

It seems evident to me that `Card.new(7, "S")` is making a 7 of Spades. This is just my curiosity, and nothing "wrong" with your code, but I'm also wondering how one would consider index 0 the "bottom". Of course, it really makes no difference, but that seems to be the "top" to me.